# Can inline formset be used in generic CBVs (CreateView or View)?

Tags: django, inline-formset

In a generic CreateView, can I use inline formset instead of usual forms as shown below?

```
class SomeView(CreateView):
    form_class = MyInlineFormSet
```

If this is possible, do I need to override any other methods? Or, how would you use a inline formset in a CBV?

UPDATE:
Following the comment from @Chris, I've tried this:

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import UpdateView

from .models import Author, Book
BookInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Author, Book, fields= 
('title',), extra=1)


class UpdateBooks(UpdateView):
   model = Book
   form_class = BookInlineFormSet
   success_url = "/"
```

And now getting this error:

ValueError at /ads/add/
save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'ad'.

Comment: If you want to create / update the related child models I believe you should use the gernic ```UpdateView``` and not the ```CreateView``` with the parent model as model in the class. Then it should work without overrides,

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I will post code below.

Comment: As I said, your model in ```UpdateBooks``` should be the parent model, which is ```Author``` in your case. So set ```model = Author```.

Comment: But then, UpdateView requires pk or id of the object that needs to be updated. How to handle the cases when you want to create an object with UpdateView?